# Recommendation System to integrate with an android app

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recommender-system

I need to build a recommendation system that takes certain parameters as input, computes a score and order suggestions to users based on this score. Well this is what I need to do loosely speaking. I am new to the scene of data science and haven't come across anything that could help me out.

This guy asked a similar question 5 years ago. I basically need something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828013/recommendation-systems-for-a-mobile-market-and-algorithm-suggestion

Apologies for the open-ended and vague question.
Just need to be pointed out in the right direction.

Edit: I do not intend to place the system on the android device. It will be running back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to sound harsh but building a recommender system on a android isn't really *Data science*.

In any recommender system context, the science on data is usually done in ad-hoc manner.

As for the algorithm implementation, validation and scaling, data science can play a part in that. But this is still not related to the fact of serving the data in a mobile application nor a website. ***That's mainly computer engineering.***

Recommender systems algorithms a quite expensive to compute on any mobile nevertheless. It's best fit to be done by a dedicated server which can also play a role in serving the information when needed. I can't get into the details of this thought as it's quite broad to fit in a single answer on the site.

I advice you to read my answer on the [time/space complexity challenge in building this types of application](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13279/solution-for-in-time-space-complexity-challenge-in-recommendation-system/13488#13488). That may help you getting some insights about the architectural design of a recommender engine in the real world.

I hope that this answers your question.

Comment: yes, I think I did not state that in the right manner. I do not intend to build the system on an android device. The system would run on a server feeding the results to the android application. I just needed the know how to implement it back-end. I shall read your answer. Thank you

Comment: Implementation isn't data science.

Comment: Again poor choice of words. But your link pointed me out in the right direction